# Issue with retrieving value based on clicked line

Tags: python, lambda

I am having issue with retrieving correctly positioned value when clicking on table cell.

The table itself is loaded from .txt file via `process_file` function and each line is separated into segments. I load segments into DataTable and I am trying to create function that is called upon tapping `TableCell` object as shown below.

The function should return the value of `pwd` segment on the line, where I clicked the `TableCell` in the loaded table. The table/page is created with Flet python module but I think my issue is related to python in general since the `on_tap` function of TableCell gets called properly.

This is my current code that returns always the last `pwd` segment in the table that got loaded from the file instead returning the segment on which I clicked:

```
def table(self):

        #ToDo - copy pwd by click on field
        def handle_account_click(pwd):
            self.main_page.set_clipboard(pwd)
        def process_file():
            contents = file()
            # Iterate over each line in the file contents
            for line in contents:
                # Split the line into segments using ' - ' as the separator
                segments = line.split(' - ')

                if len(segments) >= 3:
                    # Extract information from each segment
                    hostname = segments[0].strip()
                    ip = segments[1].strip()
                    pwd = segments[2].strip()
                    description = ' - '.join(segments[3:]).strip()

                    row = ft.DataRow(
                        cells=[
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(hostname), on_tap=lambda _: handle_account_click(pwd)),
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(ip)),
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(description))
                        ])

                    tableDefinition.rows.append(row)
                else:
                    description = None
                    row = ft.DataRow(
                        cells=[
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(hostname)),
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(ip)),
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(description))
                        ])

                    tableDefinition.rows.append(row)

        def file():
            with open('output.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                contents = file.readlines()
                return contents

        tableDefinition = ft.DataTable(
            expand=True,
            heading_row_color=ft.colors.with_opacity(0.1, ft.colors.GREEN_400),
            column_spacing=20,
            border_radius=10,
            data_row_height=50,
            vertical_lines=ft.BorderSide(width=BORDER, color='grey'),
            border=ft.border.all(BORDER, 'grey'),
            columns=[
                ft.DataColumn(label=ft.Text('Hostname')),
                ft.DataColumn(label=ft.Text('IP address')),
                ft.DataColumn(label=ft.Text('Description'))
            ],
            rows=[]
        )
        process_file()
        return tableDefinition
```

I have tried to tweak lambda expression a bit but was no success as well as following [this very similar Youtube project](https://github.com/codingjq/flet-password-locker/blob/main/main.py).